# Logstash grok filter regex

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm trying to clear up a log entry within an ELK stack using grok. I have the following text to still tackle:

```
/mnt/drive/fish/Cap Camel/Indigo - [Fair Game].jpg (34523) [2,0,34523,0,0,2,2]
/mnt/drive/fish/Cap Camel/Indigo - [Fair Game].jpg
/mnt/drive/fish/Cap Camel (1358)/Indigo - [Fair Game].jpg
```

I want the path but it contains spaces, caps and special characters etc?

Thanks

Comment: Try `^(?<file>(?:/[^/]+)+\.jpg)`

Comment: I should've been clear, the files aren't always jpg, could be any extension. The path in effect ends with the first (

Comment: Then try `^(?<file>.*?)\s*\(`, if the file path goes until whitespaces + `(` right after.

Comment: Works well, however I've discovered that some entries the path is the last item after all (no bracketed elements after). Is it possible to attempt two pattern matches?

Comment: I've updated the examples. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Use `^(?<file>.*\.[A-Za-z]+\b)\s*(\(|$)`

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your third example contains " (", we can't use that to spot the change in the first line.

The only think that seems to tie these lines together is the ".jpg".  You said that it may not always be jpg, but hopefully they all have suffixes.

With that assumption - and also that the path itself doesn't contain any periods, this pattern works in the debugger:

```
(?<file>[^\.]*\.[^ ]*)
```

"Anything that is not a period, followed by a period, followed by anything that is not a space".

Comment: Thanks for all your help. In the end used more than one if your solutions by using the `_grokparsefailure` tag to fix items not matched by grok.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using GPFs for logic control.  You can put multiple patterns in the same grok.

Comment: I might explore that approach, thanks for the heads up. Will help trim the configuration a little.